# Why are my flash messages not displaying the correct colours and button?

Tags: python, html

My flash messages aren't showing the correct colours and the 'x' button is in the wrong place. what have i done wrong?

this is from my base.html file:

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
     {% if messages %}
       {% for category, message in messages %}
       {% if catgeory == 'error' %}
       <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
           {{ message }}
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
       </div>
       {% else %}
       <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
           {{ message }}
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
       </div>
       {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
     {% endwith %}
```

This is from my auth.py file:

```html
@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method =='POST':
        firstName = request.form.get('firstName')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        if len(firstName) < 2:
            flash('First Name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be atleast 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Account created!', category='success')

    return render_template("sign_up.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have typos in your code.
For example "category" is written as "catgeory" in if statement in base.html file.
Also take a look at your div tag. The correct bootstrap styling is `class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"`.
Probably the x button will be at the right place if you edit "alter-dismissable".

Comment: thank for your help seems to of fixed everything but the 'x' button. its still not on the right side of the screen and it still is unresponsive

Comment: The fact that the button is unresponsive (I interpret it as "does nothing") can be caused by missing Bootstrap javascript files. Make sure you have not only the CSS part, but also the JS part of the Bootstrap ["Getting started"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) page.